# Why do I never see notification on tablet

Tags: android, push-notification

I followed this tutorial/example and it mostly works. 
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#app

When the web service sends out the notification. It comes down into the send notification method with the correct message. The problem is I never see an actual notification on the tablet (it is running not the latest but a newer version of android, I also tried it on 2 tablets).

Here is what my sendNotification looks like. Any ideas?
I have one activity in the app and that is "MainActivity" here if it matters.

```
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                        .setContentTitle("My Messages")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText("test"))
                        .setContentText("Test");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is running? There is nothing obviously wrong with it, IMHO.

Comment: I am sure, I can debug in there and everything looks good. I am new to android/notifications, this should show up when you do the pull down at the top right?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification) setSmallIcon() is required

Comment: "this should show up when you do the pull down at the top right?" -- that depends a bit on the tablet and the Android version running on it. However, usually it would be top left (for devices where the clock is in a status bar on the top) or bottom right (for devices where the clock is in the navigation bar on the bottom). And my apologies for missing the `setSmallIcon()` requirement.

Comment: It was the setSmallIcon. That sucks, I spent a long time on this and it not working, seems like there would be an exception or run time error or compilation error, something.

Comment: I should probably turn my comment into an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Notifications Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification) the notification must have at least

- A small icon, set by `setSmallIcon()`
- A title, set by `setContentTitle()`
- Detail text, set by `setContentText()`

So `setSmallIcon()` is required.

What the documentation doesn't mention is that if something is missing it'll just silently not work without any warnings.